# First Array Item Gets Overwritten Be Second Pushed Into Array, And Increment Duplicate Properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have a function in which I'm scheduling reminders on mobile. I'm building out an array of repeating items and incrementing two properties of each object submitted to the array, everything else in the object stays the same. When I start the first iteration of the loop, it pushes the object into the array as expected, but the second iteration updates the 'reminderId' value INSIDE the array before I ever step into the object or push function while debugging. The 'time_to_notify' increments as expected, only the 'reminderId' gets replaced.

On the next iteration it increments and I end up with an array that looks like this:

```
[
0{id: 2, title: "Athens", text: "Test", at: Tue Dec 13 2016 16:00:28 GMT-0600 (CST)}
1{id: 3, title: "Athens", text: "Test", at: Wed Dec 14 2016 16:00:28 GMT-0600 (CST)}
2{id: 3, title: "Athens", text: "Test", at: Thu Dec 15 2016 16:00:28 GMT-0600 (CST)}
]
```

Should look like this:

```
[
0{id: 1, title: "Athens", text: "Test", at: Tue Dec 13 2016 16:00:28 GMT-0600 (CST)}
1{id: 2, title: "Athens", text: "Test", at: Wed Dec 14 2016 16:00:28 GMT-0600 (CST)}
2{id: 3, title: "Athens", text: "Test", at: Thu Dec 15 2016 16:00:28 GMT-0600 (CST)}
]
```

Notice that the dates incremented correctly, but there is an issue with how the 'reminderId' is incrementing and I've been banging my head for hours.

My code that builds this is below. It's probably something super simple, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
if(isIOS){
      var notificationItem = [];
      var reminderId = -1;
      for(i=0; i < 3; i++){

          var iOSNotification = {};
          if ($scope.scheduledContainer.length == 0 && notificationItem.length == 0) {
            reminderId = 1;
          } else if ($scope.scheduledContainer.length > 0) {
            var convertDate = new Date(time_to_notify);
            convertDate.setDate(convertDate.getDate()+1);
            time_to_notify = convertDate;

          var max = $scope.scheduledContainer.reduce(function(prev, current) {
            return (prev.y > current.y) ? prev : current
          }); //$scope.scheduledContainer contains array items if they alreay exist
            reminderId = ++max.id;
        } else if (notificationItem.length > 0) {
            var convertDate = new Date(time_to_notify);
            convertDate.setDate(convertDate.getDate()+1);
            time_to_notify = convertDate;

          var max = notificationItem.reduce(function(prev, current) {
            return (prev.y > current.y) ? prev : current
          }); //notificationItem is a temp array that contains first time notification repeats
            reminderId = ++max.id;
        }


        iOSNotification = {
          id: reminderId,
          title: mxAppConfig.RegionId,
          text: task.msg,
          at: time_to_notify
        }


        notificationItem.push(iOSNotification);

      }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change pre-increment

```
reminderId = ++max.id;
```

to post-increment

```
reminderId = max.id++;
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but no go. Here's the array now: [0{id: 2, title: "Athens", text: "Test", at: Tue Dec 13 2016 16:15:52 GMT-0600 (CST)}
1{id: 2, title: "Athens", text: "Test", at: Wed Dec 14 2016 16:15:52 GMT-0600 (CST)}
2{id: 1, title: "Athens", text: "Test", at: Thu Dec 15 2016 16:15:52 GMT-0600 (CST)}]

Comment: why can't you just use `id: i + 1`? I think I'm not exactly sure about some of the functionality.

Comment: because it looks at an array of objects that could possible be pre-existing to this function call and needs to find the 'max' id number in the array and then start incrementing from there. That would simplify it, but I don't have that option.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was adding a reference to the object just before I pushed it into the array. This was holding an instance to the object which would automatically update the 'id' property in the array. Removing that and building the object as I collected the values from the if/else statements built a new object to push each time.